# Stress regulation in mosquitoes

Tags: neuroscience, entomology, chemical-communication

I was just trying to understand how in insects, specifically mosquitoes does the process of emergency responding, stress regulation take place? Or in simpler words how are flight, fright and fight situations handled?

I understand that insects have a ganglion system and they do, suitably, respond to external stimuli, but I would like to know if there is any chemical coordination that works specifically in emergency situations just as adrenalin and nor-adrenalin do in our case.

Comment: see [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16019603)

Comment: Does this mean that besides inducing long term effects, as suggested in the article, dopamine also induces the same temporary effects (like flying with greater speed and trying to escape when in danger) in insects as adrenalin does in our case?